# Get all profiles in lat/long + range (laravel - laravel-mysql-spatial)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, spatial-query

I am trying to build a form in my laravel app to get all users' profiles that are in or x km around one selected city from my cities table. I'm trying to use the laravel-mysql-spatial that makes use of the ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE mysql function but cant really wrap my brain around the eloquent stuff needed

Basicly each profile is linked to a certain city that has a location POINT() field but i would like to be able to return all profiles that are x km around a city i select via a form.

User model:

```
public function profile() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

Profile model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
    
public function city() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

City model:

```
protected $spatialFields = [
    'location'
];

public function profiles() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Profile');
}
```

the laravel-mysql-spatial has the following function to calculate distance between 2 points

```
distanceSphere($point, $point, $range);
```

but cant really figure out how/where to plug it in to get the desired output

```
User::with(['reviews', 'profile', 'profile.media','profile.city', 'categories'])->where(['type' => 'mester'])
```

this is gets my users/profiles

```
if (!empty($request->get('city_id')))
    $users_query->whereHas('profile', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->where(['city_id' => $request->get('city_id')]);
    });
```

and im using this to filter by city when selecting a city.

```
$request->input('range')
```

im getting this via a range input as distance

I've already looked similar questions up but wasnt able to wire everything together to get the desired output. Any help would be greatly apreciated

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. If you need to get all cities within a given distance you'd do `City::distanceSphere('location', $point, $distance)` where `$point` would be a `Geometry` of some sort and distance a number (i guess). This is just from a look at https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial

Comment: i did figure out how the function works... i cant figure out how to wire the function in my eloquent queries to get the desired output. this is probabily more of an eloquent/mysql function than a mysql-spatial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `whereHas` on the profile.city instead of the profile:

```
$otherCityPoint = City::where('id', $request->city_id)->value('location');
$users_query->whereHas('profile.city', function (Builder $query) use ($request,$otherCityPoint) {
    $query->distanceSphere('location', $otherCityPoint, $request->input('range') * 1000);  // 3 arg is meters
});
```

This should return all users who have profiles which have a city which is within the given distance.

Comment: i've gotten this far myself.. how would i pass the 2nd point to the function? right now im doing $query->distanceSphere('location', new Point(0,0, 4326), $request->input('range') * 10000000000); and as expected i get everything in the table